# Constraint violation on insert

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

With the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE `Play` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `room_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_FEBB7184A76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_FEBB718454177093` (`room_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_2DA17977F85E0677` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_2DA17977A188FE64` (`nickname`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_2DA17977E7927C74` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `User` VALUES(1, 'user', 'nickname', 'user@user.de');

CREATE TABLE `Room` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `Room` VALUES(1);

ALTER TABLE `Play`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `play_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `play_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `Room` (`id`);
```

And trying to run the following statement

```
INSERT INTO `Play` (`id` ,`user_id` ,`room_id`) VALUES (NULL ,  '1',  '1')
```

I get an error

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`play`, CONSTRAINT `play_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`))
```

Both data sets, #1 of User and #1 of Room exist in the databse. How can this fail? I am quite familiar with SQL, but I have no idea what the error is in this case...

Comment: Sound silly but just to make sure what do you get when you do select id from `User` where id = '1' ?

Comment: Well, if I check for `1`, I get the user. If I check for `'1'`, I get an error, naturally... But why does the query try to insert `'1'`? I created it using phpMyAdmin, and it automatically added the `'`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It was an issue that only comes up when using MySQL 5.5.9, InnoDB and Mac OS X 10.6

See: [MySQL Bug #60309](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60309)

I changed the `.conf` of MySQL to add this line:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

And it works now. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies only in the order in which you are executing the queries. The tables "User" and "Room" must be defined before you create a foreign key constraint on them.

Comment: That's only because I exported them in that order. All the tables already exist.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. Because, I copy pasted your exact queries (with the order changed) into MySQL and the insert worked just fine!

Comment: So, maybe a setting somewhere?